# Activity and service both reference the same object

Tags: android, android-service

If I have an activity that starts a background service so that the service remains when the activity is destroyed. And I need both the Service and the activity to be a referencing the same object ( because this object is expensive to construct and lives with the app as long as it is on). Then how can I achieve that? Global static variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you cannot.  A `Service` is fundamentally different than an `Activity`.  Each as a separate lifecycle, making them transient.  If you really need to retain some type of static within your app, you could very carefully create a singleton class or possibly embed it in a custom class derived from `Application`.

Comment: Well how you combat this this common problem then: User clicks on a button which does an update to an object. Service runs on background and also do an update to the same object.  I guess Singleton it is but I am surprised that there is no handy method where service and activity can share data (except for shared preferences)

Comment: Activity can bind to a service upon creation

Comment: And I assume I can bind the activity to the service even after activity is destroyed and recreated, right?

Comment: Yes, you can use a bind when an `Activity` is created again.  If the `Service` is already running then it will connect with it.  A `SharedPreference` is fine for config type items, as well as a database.  But, if you're going the database route then you'll likely be better served to just wrap it in a `ContentProvider`.  It really all depends on what it is you are "sharing" between the two.